# VBScript to check for registry key doesn't work when "option explicit" set

Tags: vbscript, registry

Okay, my first post here so hopefully I don't screw up too badly and bring the whole Internet down on top of me...

I have a simple function to check whether or not a registry key exists.  It works as I expect, until I set "option explicit".  Then it doesn't.  No errors, it just doesn't return a correct value and I cannot figure out why.  Undoubtedly it's a stupid error, and more than likely I'll slink away in shame when you all point out just how stupid it is, but as long you tell me what I'm doing wrong first it'll be worth it.

Here is the code:

```
'option explicit

if keyExists("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\WritingInCode\Company\CreateCabinetDB\") then
    wscript.echo "Key exists"
else
    wscript.echo "Key doesn't exist"
end if

function keyExists(key)
    dim objShell : set objShell = createObject("WScript.Shell")

    on error resume next

    entry = objShell.regRead(key)

    select case err.number
        case 0: keyExists = true
        case else: keyExists = false
    end select

    err.clear

    set objShell = nothing
end function
```

Comment: Wow...answered in 34 seconds! Yes, the problem was that I didn't didn't declare "entry".  And it was a dumb mistake, like I thought.  Thanks for the (amazingly) quick, non-hostile answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, here is what is happening.

1. You set `option explicit` so that when a non-declared variable is encountered, the interpreter shall raise an error.
2. Before you reach the first non-declared variable, `entry`, you switch off error handling with `on error resume next`.
3. Then you encounter `entry` and an error is raised, but not reported.
4. Execution resumes and the non-declared variable error is interpreted by the `select case` statement. And so `keyExists` always returns `false`.

Fix the problem by declaring `entry` before attempting to use it:

```
dim entry : entry = objShell.regRead(key)
```